# My custom plugin is not being called after installation in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I created a custom plugin and installed in joomla 2.5. It must be called when user logins.

My plugin has following code..

```
class plgUserZencartlogin extends JPlugin
 {

       public function __construct(& $subject, $config){
           parent::__construct($subject, $config);
           $this->loadLanguage();
       }

       public function onUserLogin($user, $options = array())
      {
           //here is my custom code..
      }

 }
```

Everything was worked fine upto installation. But is not getting triggered. I've gone through "onUserLogin" event, where it is shown that, it must be triggered automatically when user logins. But nothing was paid off for my hardwork. Thanks in advance..

Comment: Did you enable the plugin from plugin manager?

Comment: Try removing all you code inside the function and add `die;`. When you login, you should see a blank screen. If not then It's most likely what @Irfan said.

Comment: If what Lodder said diddn't work (e.g. it didn't die), then try moving the die() function call to the beginning of the file. If it still didn't die, then there is something wrong with the installation of the file. Also, don't forget to disable your cache.

Comment: yes.. it's working.. there is a problem in installation.. thank you very much friends..